# Serverless | I can’t create a new project using AWS NodeJs template

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, serverless

Running `serverless create --template aws-nodejs --path test` in the terminal, I found an error:

```
C:\Users\p????>serverless create --template aws-nodejs --path test
(node:25984) Warning: Setting the NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED environment variable to '0' makes TLS connections and HTTPS requests insecure by disabling certificate verification.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
Environment: win32, node 17.9.0, framework 3.12.0, plugin 6.2.1, SDK 4.3.2
Docs:        docs.serverless.com
Support:     forum.serverless.com
Bugs:        github.com/serverless/serverless/issues

Error:
Could not download template. Ensure that you are using the latest version of Serverless Framework: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Users\P????\AppData\Local\Temp\examples\aws-node-env-variables-encrypted-in-a-file\secrets.dev.yml.encrypted'
```